# SUMIFS in Table not working with multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs, excel-tables

Well,

I cannot get this to work for the life of me…

This formula works:

```
=SWITCH([@YTD],CurrentFY,(SWITCH(COUNTIFS($AG$2:$AG2,[@[Client Name]],$AJ$2:$AJ2,CurrentFY),1,SUMIFS([Amount (converted).amount],[Client Name],[@[Client Name]],[YTD],CurrentFY),0)),0)
```

[image: Formula for all Clients - Working]

This formula works. But this takes all Amount Converted for all Clients in FY23. It’s when I try and filter for the specifics for Quotes, Amendments & Re-Works

Quotes: (SPILL)

```
=SWITCH([@YTD],CurrentFY,(SWITCH(COUNTIFS($AG$2:$AG2,[@[Client Name]],$AJ$2:$AJ2,CurrentFY),1,SUMIFS([Amount (converted).amount],[Client Name],[@[Client Name]],[YTD],CurrentFY,[Proposal Type],{"Quote","RFP","RFQ","Ballpark","Proposal","Options","Price per Sample"}),0)),0)
```

Amendment: (Works)

```
=SWITCH([@YTD],CurrentFY,(SWITCH(COUNTIFS($AG$2:$AG2,[@[Client Name]],$AJ$2:$AJ2,CurrentFY),1,SUMIFS([Amount (converted).amount],[Client Name],[@[Client Name]],[YTD],CurrentFY,[Proposal Type],"Amendment"),0)),0)
```

Re-Works (SPILL)

```
=SWITCH([@YTD],CurrentFY,(SWITCH(COUNTIFS($AG$2:$AG2,[@[Client Name]],$AJ$2:$AJ2,CurrentFY),1,SUMIFS([Amount (converted).amount],[Client Name],[@[Client Name]],[YTD],CurrentFY,[Proposal Type],{"Quote Re-Work","Amendment Re-Work"}),0)),0)
```

[image: Formula with the required filtering - Not working for QUOTES or RE-WORKS]

Any idea how to fix this? I tried TRANSPOSE but it also didn’t work. I also tried using the different criterias (e.g. [Proposal Type],"Quote",[Proposal Type],"RFP",[Proposal Type],"RFQ",[Proposal Type],"Ballpark",[Proposal Type],"Proposal") but this didn’t work either.

Any ideas would be helpful

Thanks,
Shea

Comment: Wrap your `SUMIFS` in a `SUM`.

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes it is just the simple things that you miss!